# Как с помощью JS открыть ссылку

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью Java Script сделать так, что-бы после загрузки определённой страницы сайта, допустим example.ru/1.html, автоматически открывалась ещё одна страница, допустим example.ru/2.html.

Comment: Создайте скрытый тег `<a target='_blank'>` и кликните на него силами js

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    window.open('https://example.ru/2.html', '_blank');
}

</script>
```

Только учтите, что браузер в большинстве случаев блокирует всплывающие окна по умолчанию, вам нужно будет разрешить открытие Pop-up-а, чтобы эфект сработал.

Comment: Тут получается ссылка открывается на любой странице сайта, а мне нужно, что-бы она открывалась именно, когда откроется страница example.ru/1.html